# How to ignore nil in command line output rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, irb

Im trying to write a pretty basic test to check if my board is outputting in the cli, however despite my code outputting correctly in irb Rspec is stating that it has got nil - what am I doing wrong with my test and how can I correct it?

```
class Make_playground
  attr_reader :game_zone
  def initialize
    @game_zone = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
  end

  def make_game
    puts " #{@game_zone[0]} | #{@game_zone[1]} | #{@game_zone[2]} "
    puts "-----------"
    puts " #{@game_zone[3]} | #{@game_zone[4]} | #{@game_zone[5]} "
    puts "-----------"
    puts " #{@game_zone[6]} | #{@game_zone[7]} | #{@game_zone[8]} "
  end
end
```

```
describe Make_playground do
    it 'can create a playground in cli' do
    player = Make_playground.new
    expect(player.make_game).to eq('|   |
-----------
   |   |
-----------
   |   |')
    end
  end
```

Comment: `make_game` returns the result of the last executed line, which is a `puts`. `puts` returns `nil`.

Comment: In `make_game` try using `["first_string", "second_string", "etc..."].join('\n')` instead. Don't puts inside method, it's better to `puts make_game`.

Comment: You should use an `output` [matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/output-matcher). The equality matcher are not suitable for checking what is an output in $stdout.